# Save UITableViewCell Checkmark Selection in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to to build a selection interface with a `UITableViewController` similar to the one in Settings -> General -> Auto Lock, and have been able to get the checkmarks working, but I cannot seem to figure out how to have the checkmark appear on the previously selected cell when the view is called again.

Here's my code for the checkmark selection so far:

```
var lastSelectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedDistance = distances[indexPath.row]
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if indexPath.row != lastSelectedIndexPath?.row {
        if let lastSelectedIndexPath = lastSelectedIndexPath {
            let oldCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastSelectedIndexPath)
            oldCell?.accessoryType = .None
        }

        let newCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        newCell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DataCell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = (lastSelectedIndexPath?.row == indexPath.row) ? .Checkmark : .None
    let distance = distances[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = distance.0
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(distance.1)"

    return cell

}
```

I'm thinking I might have to store lastSelectedIndexPath in another file but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you answered your own question here. You need to store lastSelectedIndexPath some how (ie to whatever you're using for persistence). A simple way (read: not the best way) to do this if you don't have any sort of database set up already is to store it using `NSUserDefaults`.